# React For Loop con onClick dentro

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy trabajando con React, tengo el siguiente código:

```
var rows = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= this.state.numberOfPages; i++) {
    rows.push(<li key={i.toString()} onClick={() => this.getResults(i)}><a href="#">{i}</a></li>)
};
```

La función `getResults()` es tan sencilla como esto:

```
getResults: function(page = this.state.currentPage) {
    console.log(page);
},
```

La variable `this.state.numberOfPages` es igual a 3. El problema se da cuando clickeo en los `<li>`, en la consola siempre imprime 4. Sin embargo los valores de `<li>` se muestran en pantalla perfectamente. Es como si cuando se asigna que parámetro va a ser pasado a la función se evaluara el ultimo valor de `i`.

Hay alguna solución que se les ocurra?

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error esta al asignar el callback al evento onClick

```
onClick={() => this.getResults(i)}
```

debes hacerlo así

```
onClick={this.getResults.bind(this, i)}
```

ademas en la declaración de la función getRessults no estas imprimiendo 'i' estas imprimiendo la pagina actual this.state.currentPage.

supongo que lo que quieres es definirla como

```
getResults: function(page) {
    console.log(page);
}
```